# Extend multiple base component in lighting web component

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to extend multiple lighting base web components?

Something like this:

```js
import externalScripts from 'c/Scripts';
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Topics extends LightningElement, externalScripts{
    @api name;
}
```

I want to use `@track`, `@api` but they are not working

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

That's not possible for prototypical inheritance. But you can use [Mix-Ins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins) to emulate multiple inheritances:

> Abstract subclasses or mix-ins are templates for classes. An ECMAScript class can only have a single superclass, so multiple inheritance from tooling classes, for example, is not possible. The functionality must be provided by the superclass.

A function with a superclass as input and a subclass extending that superclass as output can be used to implement mix-ins in ECMAScript:

```js
let calculatorMixin = Base => class extends Base {
  calc() { }
};

let randomizerMixin = Base => class extends Base {
  randomize() { }
};
```

A class that uses these mix-ins can then be written like this:

```js
class Foo { }
class Bar extends calculatorMixin(randomizerMixin(Foo)) { }
```

Some additional resources:
[Mixins for Web Components](https://component.kitchen/elix/mixins)

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is also checking if the passed class to mixin is an instance of Lightning Element.

Edit:

```
function assertIsLightningElementSubclass(Base) {
    const baseProto = Base.prototype;

    if (typeof baseProto.dispatchEvent !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError(`${Base} must be an Element type`);
    }
}
```

You are more than welcome to check this: https://beyondthecloud.dev/blog/mixins-in-lwc-dreamforce-2022
out and use it as a base for your mixins.